# Change the setup language while setup is running (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

How to add the choice of language to the first page, as it is shown in the video?

http://screencast.com/t/SDI5VN67LFL

[image]

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021292/inno-setup-language-selector-with-vcl-styles), it does what you wanted:

```pascal
[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=False
ShowLanguageDialog=no
{...}

[Languages]
Name: "English"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "French"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "German"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "Spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
//Add languages as you like ...
{...}

[Code]
var
  LangCombo: TNewComboBox;
  SelectLangLabel: TNewStaticText;
  LangArray: Array of String;
  IsConfirm: Boolean;

function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation, lpFile, lpParameters, lpDirectory: String; nShowCmd: Integer): THandle;
external 'ShellExecuteW@shell32.dll stdcall';

function IsSetLang: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}') = '');
end;

function IsActiveLang: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (LangArray[LangCombo.ItemIndex] = ActiveLanguage);
end;

function ActiveLang: Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to (GetArrayLength(LangArray) - 1) do
  begin
    if (LangArray[I] = ActiveLanguage) then Result := I;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  IsConfirm := True;

  LangCombo := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  LangCombo.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
  LangCombo.Top := WizardForm.Bevel.Top - LangCombo.Height - ScaleY(55);
  LangCombo.Left := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Left;
  LangCombo.Width := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Width;
  LangCombo.Style := csDropDownList;

  SelectLangLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  SelectLangLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
  SelectLangLabel.Top := LangCombo.Top - SelectLangLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
  SelectLangLabel.Left := LangCombo.Left;
  SelectLangLabel.Caption := SetupMessage(msgSelectLanguageLabel);

  LangCombo.Items.Add('English'); //ItemIndex: 0 - English
  LangCombo.Items.Add('Français'); //ItemIndex: 1 - French
  LangCombo.Items.Add('Deutsch'); //ItemIndex: 2 - German
  LangCombo.Items.Add('Español'); //ItemIndex: 3 - Spanish
  //Add languages as you like, but make sure the order matches the order of the languages in the array.

  SetArrayLength(LangArray,LangCombo.Items.Count);

  LangArray[0] := 'English'; //=ItemIndex: 0
  LangArray[1] := 'French'; //=ItemIndex: 1
  LangArray[2] := 'German'; //=ItemIndex: 2
  LangArray[3] := 'Spanish'; //=ItemIndex: 3
  //Add languages as you like, but make sure the order matches the order of the languages in the combobox.

  LangCombo.ItemIndex := ActiveLang; //set default language as active language
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: THandle;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = wpWelcome) and not IsActiveLang then
  begin
    Result := False;
    IsConfirm := False;
    ResultCode := ShellExecute(0,'',ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'),'/LANG='+LangArray[LangCombo.ItemIndex],'',SW_SHOW);
    if ResultCode <= 32 then MsgBox(Format('Running installer with the selected language failed. Code: %d',[ResultCode]), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    WizardForm.Close;
  end;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = wpWelcome) and IsSetLang;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  Cancel := True;
  Confirm := IsConfirm;
end;
```

[image: combobox of languages in WelcomePage]

This code demonstrates how to create a language combobox on the WelcomePage, but can of course be replaced with any other or custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Setup]
ShowLanguageDialog=yes
ShowUndisplayableLanguages=yes

[Languages]
Name: "cz"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Czech.isl";   
Name: "de"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl";  
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl";
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that when the installer is running, the language cannot be changed in the standard way. I saw this question in which the author achieved the desired result by adding several of his own functions (function GetAvailableLanguages: TStringList and procedure SetChosenLanguage(const I:integer) )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370054/inno-setup-change-the-setup-language-while-setup-is-running?rq=1

Maybe someone knows what he added, what code is in these functions.
P S sorry for my English translate via Google translator.

Comment: But did you notice that the @radiolondra added those function to Inno Setup **compiler**, not to .iss script? And that it actually does not work fully?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the language on Inno Setup installer while it is running. The installer on the video must be using some custom build of Inno Setup.

But you can *re-start* the installer with a new language. See these related questions:

- [Choosing install language programmatically in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49940836/850848)
- [Change the setup language while setup is running (Inno Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61407724/850848)